# Can't find mysql config

Tags: mysql, configuration, my.cnf

I uses CentOS on my server that installed from hosting distributive.
System works well, but i can't find mysql config to fix some things.
I can see only mysql log file named as hostingname.err in /var/lib/mysql folder.

File search:
find / -name "*my*cnf" doesn't find any files, exept default configs from /usr/share
and default /etc/my.cnf doesn't works after any changes, because it isn't used by Mysqld.

Text search at system files:
find / -type f -exec grep «hostingname.err» {} \; doesn't appears any results

Please, help me with any ideas to find correct my cnf that used by Mysql.

Thanks.

Comment: mysqladmin variables also doesn't show the location of the mysql config

Comment: [See location of my.cnf file on macOS](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54879574/1896134)

Answer (score 2):

Running `/usr/libexec/mysqld --help --verbose` should give you the default config files location. The top line of the output should look something like this -

```
Default options are read from the following files in the given order:
/etc/mysql/my.cnf /etc/my.cnf ~/.my.cnf
```

If that doesn't work, try running `ps aux | grep -i mysqld` and see if the default config file has been overridden with the option  `--defaults-file=`  to read default options from the given file.